escaping backslashes in MySQL for CSV interpretation
In my S3, I have a CSV file that looks like this:
"id","created_at","subject","description","priority","status","recipient","recipient_id",   

Now, one of the description column's row looks like this:
"
Internet Marketing Experts 

Note: If you are not interested, then you can reply with a simple \"NO\",We will never contact you again.
"

This has normal text but also some special characters. Notice this part in the cell's value:
\"NO\",We

The first comma (,) after interested does not cause an issue. But the second comma \"NO\",We causes a split and We goes into the next column (priority) when loaded into MySQL. Even though it should be a part of the same column (description).
Now I use this to load data from S3 into MySQL:
f"""LOAD DATA FROM S3 's3://{s3_bucket_name}/{s3_key}'
                    REPLACE
                    INTO TABLE {schema_name}.stg_tickets
                    CHARACTER SET utf8mb4
                    FIELDS 
                        TERMINATED BY ','
                        ENCLOSED BY '"'
                    IGNORE 1 LINES
                    (id, created_at, subject, 
                    description, priority, status, recipient)
"""

This works for all other cases because there are not a lot of commas/special characters in other description rows. But this particular record messes up the columns because it cannot distinguish the content properly.
I want to handle it using the MySQL command itself. Pre-processing the S3 files wouldn't be an option at the moment.
Note: I am running the query using Python.
I have already tried ESCAPED BY but although it doesn't throw an error, it doesn't make any difference on the data split either:
FIELDS                         
                        TERMINATED BY ','
                        ENCLOSED BY '"'
                        ESCAPED BY '\\\\'

What else could I try?
Edit:
I managed to try it via SQL itself:
ESCAPED BY '\\'

When I try via with this, it still splits the data incorrectly. I know because I get this error:
SQL Error [1366] [HY000]: Incorrect integer value: 'info@xxx' for column 'recipient' at row 781

info@xxx was supposed to be the recipient value but now its trying to load it into the next column. So basically after the split, all values move towards the right.
If I use:
ESCAPED BY '\\\\'

I get this:
SQL Error [1083] [42000]: Field separator argument is not what is expected; check the manual

Example CSV file:
id,subject,description,priority,status,recipient,requester_id,submitter_id,assignee_id,organization_id,group_id,collaborator_ids,follower_ids,forum_topic_id,problem_id
4232222,May I send you an invoice?,"Hi,
 
My packages are reasonable and more importantly they generate a number of quality new leads daily.
 
Thanks & Regards,
Rodigoria

Test Company Name 

 

Note: If you are not interested then you can reply with a simple \""NO\"",We will never contact you again.",normal,new,info@xxxx.de,2345678,2345678,,,,[],[],,


You'll want to add ESCAPED BY as well.

Also make sure to not only tell us your problem, but also asking a question. Proof reading your text and using proper formatting would help, too.

MySQL needs the backslash escaped, so MySQL should eventually "see" ESCAPED BY '\\' in your query. Not sure if additional escaping to satisfy the python syntax is necessary here or not.

Awful. First try to make it work by an SQL query alone without Python (thus checking if you really want \\ or even \). Then build Python around it.

In Python, use a raw string so you don't need to escape the backslashes twice: rf"""..."""

Yes, that's what I'm suggesting.

It definitely should. Does it work if you run the query by hand, instead of from Python?

Managed to try via SQL itself. Please see the edited qs @Barmar still the same tho

Try changing ENCLOSED BY to OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY.

Tried that but it gives the same error due to wrong split @Barmar

Can you provide a sample of the entire line of the CSV file, so we can copy it and try ourselves?

Uploaded to gdrive here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1t3lEAFjLGG1h_5A1xRwPRrKKNZdVm1fF/view?usp=sharing would it work for you? @Barmar

The file contains \""NO\"" instead of \"NO\"

Either double the delimiter or escape it, but not both.

Could you give an example? @Barmar

Either ""NO"" or \"NO\" in the CSV.
